# Consistent matplotlib text placement regardless of machine

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a Python plotting script that is working well on my work computer (top example). However, when running the script on my personal laptop, much of the text is out of place, and formatting of some subplots is wrong (bottom example).

[image: Working image]
[image]

Is there a straightforward way to base text coordinates on the dimension/resolution of the figure and/or screen, rather than absolute position? Note that these two images are the same sizes and resolution, though, so I may be barking up the wrong tree.

Also, I see that aspect and sharey seem to be handled differently between the two versions (based on the top and bottom axes of imshow here). Is there a reason for this?

My goal is to make this script (and others) usable regardless of platform, and this isn't the first time I have run into such issues. Thanks for your help!

[Edit] Some example code (the whole script is over 1500 lines)...

```
# Setting figsize early
from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (3200./500.,2400./500.)

# Calling figure/subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(9, 1, sharex=True, sharey=False, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]})

# A couple imshow calls
elif v == 'gust':
    im = axs[7].imshow(vals,cmap=var[v]['cmap'],vmin=var[v]['vmin'],vmax=var[v]['vmax'],interpolation='nearest',aspect=asp)
elif v == 'wdir':
    im = axs[8].imshow(vals,cmap=var[v]['cmap'],vmin=var[v]['vmin'],vmax=var[v]['vmax'],interpolation='nearest',aspect=asp,alpha=0.5)

# Saving the figure
plt.savefig('%s_%s.png' %(s,str(int(flen))),dpi=500,pad_inches=0.05)
```

Comment: Added some code snippets. Let me know if there's anything else that would be relevant.